# postgres(redshift) query including to_char and group by returns some errors

Tags: amazon-redshift

Im using redshift now.
then Id like to run query like

```
SELECT to_char(created_at, 'HH24') AS hour , to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS tmp FROM log GROUP BY tmp;
```

this returns error, when I do it in mysql, it seems to be good.
this error is

```
ERROR:  column "log.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

when I changed group by clause like "group by created_at", it returns results, but it has duplicated list.

Is is due to redshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `GROUP BY` clause, any column in your query must either appear in the clause or you have to specify how you want it to be aggregated.

In your case, you seem to be trying to aggregate your `log` entries by hour.  I suggest using the postgres date manipulation functions, for example:

```
  SELECT created_at::date AS date, 
         extract('HOUR' FROM created_at) as hour 
    FROM log 
GROUP BY date, hour;
```

Comment: thx LGTM!  Is there a good way to express 00-24 hour? extract(Hour) seem to return 0-24

Comment: @mo12mo34 you can use to_char to fix hour numeric format. Use to_char(extract('HOUR' FROM created_at), '00').